# What's the best way to unpack a list of frozensets?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not allowed to use any import.

Input:

```
[frozenset({1}), frozenset({32}), frozenset({40}), frozenset(), frozenset({76})]
```

Desired Output:

```
[1,32,40,76]
```

I'm looking for a concise way. I know how to unpack it with a muli-line for loop.

Comment: i simply couldn't figure out how... why is this a bad quesiton? i know it's easy

Comment: Why is it insufficient to wrap the multi-line for loop in a well-named function?

Comment: You should include your current code, it would be a starting point for asking for a more concise way.

Comment: The 1st answer is the what I meant. It's the most obvious and clear. But i was wondering if there's a one-line solution to this question. You can simply say no if there isn't.

Comment: Regarding your comment about improving your question: downvotes are anonymous, and the general consensus is to avoid commenting when downvoting. One downvote is nothing out of the ordinary, so you shouldn't worry too much about it. Guesses about ossible reasons: you didn't include your current attempt, which could make your question look like "write this code for me", which is frequently frowned upon here (a downvote reason is "does not show reasearch effort"). Also, it would have given a reference for what you consider "not concise enough", making your expectation clearer.

Comment: good point. i didn't include because i thought it's too obvious.. but to other people maybe the answers are too obvious too lol..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to generate the output. In order to extract the value in each frozenset, you can create an iterator on it and use the `next()` method of the iterator to get the first and unique value, if it is not empty:

```
lst =  [frozenset({1}), frozenset({32}), frozenset({40}), frozenset(), frozenset({76})]

out = [next(iter(fset)) for fset in lst if fset]

print(out)
# [1, 32, 40, 76]
```

Comment: May I ask a follow-up question? Your code works well when I tested it alone. I wanted to actually include it in a return line. So I used ' return [next(iter(i) for i in lst if i)] ' and I got [<set_iterator object at 0x7fce40017ec0>].. any clue?

Comment: You mixed up the parentheses - it's `[next(iter(i))` << both closed here ... `for i in lst if i]`

Comment: Your expression created a generator expression `(iter(i) for i in lst if i)`, that yields iterators on each frozenset, and calling `next` on it returned the first one of these iterators.

Comment: yes ..>__'' my bad. too late for coding. thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate in the list of frozenset, and change their datatype to list
[See here](https://www.askpython.com/python/list/convert-set-to-list-python)

```py
l = [frozenset({1}), frozenset({32}), frozenset({40}), frozenset(), frozenset({76})]
arr = []
for element in l:
    new = list(element)
    if new != []:
        arr.append(new[0])
print(arr)
```

Comment: Note that it is more usual to write `if new != []:` simply as `if new:`, as lists (and more generally all container objects, like sets, dicts, as well as strings) are considered `True` in boolean context if they're not empty.

Comment: good explanation. The real reason i got stuck at the one liner is i didn't write `if fset` part properly.